# Debian: Unable to mount a second drive as a subdirectory inside of another partition

Tags: linux, debian, mount, ext3, fstab

I have the following `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>     <type>      <options>                  <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc             proc        defaults                   0       0
/dev/md1        /                 ext3        defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/md0        /boot             ext3        defaults                   0       2
/dev/md5        /home             ext3        defaults                   0       2
/dev/md3        /opt              ext3        defaults                   0       2
/dev/md6        /tmp              ext3        defaults                   0       2
/dev/md2        /usr              ext3        defaults                   0       2
/dev/md4        /var              ext3        defaults                   0       2
/dev/md7        none              swap        sw                         0       0
/dev/sdc        /home/httpd       ext3        defaults                   0       2
/dev/hda        /media/cdrom0     udf,iso9660 user,noauto                0       0
/dev/sdc1       /mnt/usb/backup-1 auto        defaults                   0       0
```

I am unable to get `/dev/sdc/`, an internal SATA hard disk, to mount at `/home/httpd/` on reboot. The `/home/httpd/` directory exists.

Mounting via `mount -t ext3 /dev/sdc /home/httpd` works just fine.

Mounting via `mount -a` generates the following error message:

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

This is, incidentally, the same message that I see while booting. The error message goes away if I comment out the line in `fstab` starting with `/dev/sdc`.

Comment: what exactly *is* /dev/sdc?  internal hard drive? USB drive?  removable card reader device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your `fstab`: you cannot simultaneously have a valid filesystem **both** on `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdc1`. One of these commands (or maybe two) will definitely fail, and as `mount /dev/sdc` works fine, the failing one is second. Also it probably prevents second mount from executing; while I don't know exactly, it should work. And if you want to check a line in `fstab` for correctness, don't specify the mountpoint: this will force `mount` to lookup it (and other options) in fstab effectively verifying your setup.